# How to load a .csv file into crossfilter with d3?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to load a .csv file into crossfilter for further use it with dc.js and d3. However, if the `ndx = crossfilter(data_)` is not inside `d3.csv(...`, it does not work. Is it possible to load data using d3 inside a global/outside variable (in this case `ndx`)?

```
 var ndx;

 private method(){

        var data_;

        d3.csv("samples.csv", function(data){

            var format = d3.timeParse("%m-%y"); 

            data.forEach(function(d: any) {
                d.date = format(d.date);
            });

            data_ = d3.csvParse(data);
        });

        ndx = crossfilter(data_);
}
```

How can I load it into crossfilter?
Am I obligated to use crossfilter inside the `d3.csv(..` call?

---

**Solution:**
I made my .csv became a .json and I loaded it 'synchronously'. Observe below.

```
 var ndx;

 private method(){

        var data_ = (function() {
            var json: any = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': "samples.json",
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data:any) {
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
        })(); 

        ndx = crossfilter(data_);
}
```

**Observe:**

> 'async': false

Comment: Could u plz share a jsFiddle

Comment: sure, here it goes: http://plnkr.co/edit/LLgY1NFOTU85MLJt79Fu?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the callback function is executed **asynchronously**, once the data is returned. This means that if you put the charting code outside of the callback, you are going to get the empty array that you defined because no data has been returned yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, what can I do to ensure that the data is available before manage it into a chart?

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite couldn't update the link along with the answer. :d

Comment: By looking in your plnkr, in the end, you just put everything inside the 'd3.csv(..' method, what exactly I would like to avoid =/.

Comment: Then you can think of some another approach. Probably you can convert CSV into JSON. Directly use this as crossfilter data.

Comment: That's what you need to do: Run everything that depends on the data from within the asynchronous callback method. You can certainly break all your code out into functions that are stored outside that scope, but you have to call them from within the callback so that they execute after the data is loaded.

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur I found a solution based on your last comment. Thanks! What should be the best thing to do now to make it fair for you. Should I send you the solution, you post, and I upvote it? How should we proceed?

Comment: @EthanJewett very nice comment, probably I will follow this hint as well. The real reason behind this issue that I am facing is that I would like to share the same crossfilter between different components (Angular2). That is why I was trying to load the data in crossfilter out of the d3.csv load. By doing that, I could load the data only once and share the crossfilter afterwards.

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite Re. the answer: I would say edit your question and add your solution on the end and mark @Aravind's solution as correct. Re. Crossfilter in Angular: Create your crossfilter object outside the `d3.csv` load so you can add it to your directive parameters or whatever, then within `d3.csv` use `crossfilter.add` to add the data to it.